# Getting rotation of a list in python

Tags: python, list

I want all possible single right shift arrays:

```
def gen(total):
    rot = []
    init = [0]*total
    init[0] = 1
    print init
    rot.append(init)
    for i in range(total-1):
        init[i] = init[i] - init[i+1]
        init[i+1] = init[i] + init[i+1]
        init[i] = init[i+1] - init[i]
        print init
        rot.append(init)
    return rot

rot = gen(8)

print rot
```

This prints

```
[1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0]
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1]
```

I want this to be list of lists. I initialise an array `rot` but appending to it creates same rows

```
[[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1]]
```

How to handle this issue?

PS: I don't want to use numpy like `numpy.eye(8)`

Comment: Show your full code with appending.

Comment: Please don't use that method to swap two numbers. It's a horrendous hack (likewise for the `xor` version) that is not very readable and it breaks down with large integers. Python already a syntax for swapping values: `init[i], init[i + 1] = init[i + 1], init[i]`.

Comment: Python has long integers with no upper limit, so that swapping technique should be safe. I do agree that it shouldn't be used though.

Comment: @Kevin That's true. It's just so unreadable compared to the proper method (in fact I find it much more opaque compared to the naïve use of a temporary variable).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Existing answers cover pretty well the problem with the existing code, so here's a different approach entirely:

```
>>> [[int(a==b) for b in range(8)] for a in range(8)]
[[1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], 
[0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0], 
[0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0], 
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1]]
```

(some newlines added to the output by me for legibility)

Answer (score 1):

You should append *a copy of the generated list* like this:

```
from copy import deepcopy

def gen(total):
    rot = []
    init = [0]*total
    init[0] = 1
    print init
    for i in range(total-1):
        init[i] = init[i] - init[i+1]
        init[i+1] = init[i] + init[i+1]
        init[i] = init[i+1] - init[i]
        #print init
        rot.append(deepcopy(init))
    return rot

rot = gen(8)
print rot
```

You also can use `copy.copy` instead of `copy.deepcopy`.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are modifying always the same object you append also always the same object. When you modify `init`, every entry of `rot` will see the change and therefore is every element the last state of `init`. To avoid this you need to create different objects and then append it to `rot`.

Answer (score 1):

Why not use a double-ended-queue?

```
import collections
def gen(total):
    init = [0]*total
    init[-1] = 1
    d = collections.deque(init)
    return [list(d) for _ in range(len(d)) if not d.rotate(1)]
```

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is that you're not copying the list, but your code seems needlessly complex.  This seems to work just as well:

```
def gen(n):
    res = [[0 for j in xrange(n)] for i in xrange(n)]
    for i in xrange(n):
        res[i][i] = 1
    return res
```